# What is the technical name of the Mobile Safari Share Button? Can it be targeted with Javascript?

Tags: mobile, ios6, mobile-safari

Does anyone know the name of this button at the bottom of IOS Mobile Safari? It's the button at the bottom of the phone that is a box with an arrow coming out of it.

Also, can it be targeted from the browser via javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode's attributes inspector the button's identifier is "Action".Mobile safari does not prove any JS API to allow us to call the social activity.But you can us other social API such as Socialist.